# in c# why I can cast an interface to any type without a compiler error

Tags: c#, interface

Consider the following code

```
IDisposable foo = <something>;
ArrayList bar = (ArrayList)foo;
```

This compiles without warning even though ArrayList does not implement IDisposable.

It seems that you can cast any interface to a class that doesn't implement that interface. Since the types of both are obvious at compile-time, why doesn't the compiler validate this?

Comment: `ArrayList` is not sealed so you could have a subclass of `ArrayList` which implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: yes you could do, but then surely the compiler should expect you to cast it to your subclass. This would force you to be explicit about the types you expect, which seems to be the point of a strongly typed language.

Comment: It is because the c# spec says so. See section 6.2.4 to see why Lee is correct.

Comment: @Lee Write it as the answer. To Andy: There might be many subclasses of `ArrayList` which might all implement this interface. Maybe all you know is that the actual type is _one_ of all those classes, but you do not know which one. And maybe the `class` in question is `internal` to another assembly, or nested `private` to another class. So maybe you cannot specify the exact class type because it is not in scope. _Addition:_ What if I had `void M(object foo) { var bar = (IDisposable)foo; /* ... */ }`. Should that not be allowed either, because I did not give the exact type, only the interface?

Comment: Casting *is* being explicit about the types you expect. I'm not sure why you're assuming the compiler should only allow a particular type of cast. In particular, `(IDisposable) (object) a` will always compile, regardless of the type of `a`. Of course you can get a runtime error, but you get what you asked for. "Strongly typed" is a term overloaded to the point of meaninglessness; if you mean by it "a language that only allows type conversions that are provably correct at compile time", then C# isn't strongly typed. Fortunately, I might add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not validate it because it could be a valid cast.

```
public class Foo : ArrayList, IDisposable
{
   ...
}
public class Bar : IDisposable
{
   ...
}

Random rand = new Random();
public IDisposable SomtimesGetArrayList()
{
    if(rand.Next(0,4) == 0)
        return new Bar();

    return new Foo();
}

//Elsewhere
IDisposable foo = SomtimesGetArrayList();
ArrayList bar = (ArrayList)foo;
```

3 out of 4 calls to `SomtimesGetArrayList` will return a object that can be successfully cast. It is too much processing effort for the compiler to check every code path and make sure that every possible way would potentially produce a object can be cast.

However, if you had a `sealed` class the compiler can make more assumptions and it does not need to check every path to know that it the cast will always fail, the following code [will fail to compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xpY0ue).

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IDisposable foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = (Bar)foo;
    }
}

public class Foo : IDisposable 
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

public sealed class Bar
{
}
```